Identifying a movie about witches running an orphange
I remember watching a film when I was a child in the 80's. I think it was a children's film, and was either British or American.
A group of witches (I think three) running an orphanage or workhouse type establishment. I remember children being forced to run on a hamster-wheel type contraption to power the machines, and another scene where some children are trying to escape and the witches are chasing them on a steam-powered vehicle of some sort. Unfortunately that's about all I can remember l, but my memories of those scenes are really vivid.

Sounds like this movie, The Wolves of Willoughby Chase (1989)
According to this site:

The film has an exquisite sense of period and some amazing sets –
  octagonal      pool tables, a vast Victorian orphanage and laundry
  where children are made to  work on giant hamster wheels.





That's it exactly! Thanks very much, can't tell you how long I've been trying to remember this film!

Glad I could help :) Do you mind marking my answer as correct?
